# indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid) *__result = *__first;

Tags: c++

I wrote the code for copying the elemnts of one array to another and I got this error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void copy(const int* a, int* b, int size =5)
{
    for ( int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    int b[5];

    copy(a,b,5);

    cout << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code which is causing a problem? Looks OK to me.

Comment: yes thats the exact code

Comment: @SergeyA That's pretty far from _OK code_ for me! Wear sharper glasses!

Comment: Oh! Using namespace std.

Answer (score 3):

You have a conflict between `std::copy` and `::copy` due to that silly `using namespace std`. `std::copy` takes different arguments, the third of which is not an `int` as it is in your version.

Either call it with `::copy` or stop using `using namespace std` altogether.

By the way, I don't understand what you expect `cout << b << endl` to do? There's no built-in formatting specialisation for arrays.

Comment: this is just to print the output

Comment: @DeeptanshuJha: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do, but I don't understand why you think `cout << b << endl` will accomplish it. What I'm saying is that _it won't_!

Answer (score 0):

Another good sample why not to use

```
using namespace std;
```

which already has a `std::copy()` function declared. It's actually implementation specific, if that function is declared, from the header files included. 
Anyway it looks like you've been drawing the short straw, and your function declaration/definition comes up being ambiguous.

You may be able to fix that, referring to the global namespace explicitly:

```
   ::copy(a,b,5);
// ^^
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/BmGpSG)

---

Also don't wonder, if you receive that pointer address value from

```
cout << b << endl;
```

that's exactly what's expected. You need a loop to output individual values from that array.

Comment: yes 
I am shifting from ruby to c++ , still trying to get a hang of the syntax.